# how to use the angular pwa schematics library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-service-worker

I see that a new library has landed or at least I just became acquainted with it. The repro steps in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10297) refer to `@angular/pwa` but I can't find any documentation for that (yet!).  Does anyone know the purpose and features of this library for an Angular CLI user? Or is the functionality transparent? I have been trying service workers by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a new schematic adding [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) capabilities to an angular app, to use it, just run `ng add @angular/pwa --project <your-project-name>` and it will create all the required files and register the service worker.

You can find more info in the [2018 ng-conf keynote](https://youtu.be/dIxknqPOWms?t=722)

Comment: thanks for the video. that was some quick uploading! the schematic is adding `manifest.json` under `assets` instead of the root. It needs to be under the root if I'm not mistaken.